# C# Windows Form set value of selectedIndex comobox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

after searching on this site i can't find the correct solution and need help.

I'm trying to modify a field of an user (I simulate that user wants to change their city)

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| id_city | name                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | India               |
|       2 | Irland              |
|       3 | France              |
+---------+---------------------+
```

And when I launch the query and I get the result I need is like that:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| id_city | name                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       3 | France              |
|       1 | India               |
|       2 | Irland              |
+---------+---------------------+
```

And in my C# code when initialize the windows forms I fill the combobox:

```
modifyCityUserComboBox.ValueMember = "id_city";
modifyCityUserComboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
modifyCityUserComboBox.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Then I try to put in the combobox the city that user have, but in this part I have the problem. When I do:

```
modifyCityUserComboBox.SelectedIndex = userDto.GetIdCity();
```

(supose that India is the original city of the user and wants to change it)

I have this error = `"Invalid argument= The value of '1' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex. Parameter name= SelectedIndex".`

I've been discovered that combobox start selectedIndex in 0 and if I don't order the cities I only need do:

```
modifyCityUserComboBox.SelectedIndex = userDto.GetIdCity() - 1;
```

With this "trick" the IdCity it's 0 and combobox accept it but I don't want do it that way. I want show the cities ordered.

I've tried set True the Sort combobox property and not order the cities in the mysql query but I get the same error...

Anyone know how can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `modifyCityUserComboBox.SelectedValue=userDto.GetIdCity();`

Comment: I've tried before but don't work as I expect. The combobox appears empty (you can open it to select another city) but not shows any city name when the windows form is loaded.

Comment: @Aker666 You just wrote "when the windows form" is loaded, but you tagged it as WPF. Is it windows form or WPF in the end? Btw why don't you sort with 'ORDER BY name' inside your query?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post. I tagged WPF by mistake. I order the name in the query, not in the form. var query = "select id_city, name from city order by name";

Comment: I found the bug on my code that did not work SelectedValue... Thanks for answer and try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you set up your classes, but this is how I've done it and it works. First I insert all cities from database to `ComboBox` list inside `Form1` constructor. After that you can press `button1` on `Form1` to change the city depending on the `User` inside `button1_Click` event. Let me demonstrate you the `Form1`:

[image: Form]

---

**Main method:**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<DataTable> dataTable = new List<DataTable>();

    string path = @"server=.\sqlexpress;database=Cities;integrated Security=True;";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(path))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select id_city, name from city order by name";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    dataTable.Add(new DataTable()
                    {
                        id_city = (int)dr["id_city"]
                       ,name = dr["name"] as string
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dataTable };
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id_city";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

---

**DataTable class:**

```
class DataTable
{
    public int id_city { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

---

**button1_Click event:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User("India");

    var myarr = comboBox1.Items.OfType<DataTable>().ToArray();

    foreach (var item in myarr)
    {
        if (item.name.Equals(user.city))
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**User class:**

```
class User
{
    public string city { get; set; }

    public User(string str)
    {
        city = str;
    }
}
```

---

Feel free to insert more cities in your database and change the country of `User` inside `button1_Click` event. Modify it the way you like, hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it works but I had an error in my code by copy-paste. Although, thanks for your answer!.